# javascript extends class get all the properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, extends, super

How can I get all the properties from extends class?

```
class Fish {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name ="this is the name"
  }
}

class Trout extends Fish {
  constructor(name, length) {
    super(name)
    this.length = "10cm"
  }
}

let newFish =new Trout()
console.log (newFish.name)
console.log (newFish.length)
```

Is there any way to get in a loop to get name,length,etc what every set it in the extends classes?

console.log(newFish[0]) something like that

Answer (score 1):

That your class uses `extends` is not really relevant, as the properties you mention are both *owned* by the constructed object, and not inherited from a prototype . Also, they are enumerable.

So you can use most of the usual iteration methods. The basic `for...in` loop will work too:

```
for (let prop in newFish) {
    console.log (prop, ":", newFish[prop])
}
```

Or `Object.keys`, `Object.values`, `Object.entries`, ...

Answer (score -1):

use the code below:

```
const myArray =  Object.values(newFish)
// you will get [ 'this is the name', '10cm' ]
```